# Choose Virtualmin PHP version

Tags: server, webserver, virtualmin

I installed virtualmin several times, but now it seems that it comes with PHP7 by default.

Is there a way to choose an older version of PHP on install? How ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Virtualmin doesn't "come with" any PHP version. It installs whatever your OS provides, by default, and supports it. This support includes versions going back as far as 4 (though deprecated, now) and as recent as 7.

Virtualmin knows how to work with multiple PHP versions, if you have multiple versions installed. It depends on your OS how you'd go about that. CentOS has SCL, which Virtualmin knows about and will auto-detect PHP when installed via SCL. I'm not sure how multiple versions are handled on Ubuntu (Eric usually handles the Ubuntu questions in our forums), but no matter what, you can always manually specify the paths to PHP for alternate versions, even if Virtualmin doesn't automatically detect them. There's an option labeled "Additional locations for PHP commands" in Virtualmin Configuration->PHP Options for setting that. It wants a full path to php-cgi, generally speaking (e.g. /usr/local/php7/bin/php-cgi if installed from source).

I don't think Ubuntu has a standard way to have older versions of PHP, but if there is, we'd add automatic support for it (if it's not already in there, as I said, I'm not super familiar with this feature on Ubuntu).